# How to separate a column of numbers from string lines of varying lengths in C++?

Tags: c++

thanks in advance for your help.
I'm looking to read a file that has the following format:

```
100      Every line has  
23452    A different number of words  
30       etc
```

If I use the method of reading line by line:

file >> number[i] >> str

It obviously doesn't work, because the string has spaces. Does anyone have any idea how else I could do this? I am only interested in saving the numbers in an array.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

using fstream there is a way to read a line and stop at a given character ( such as a space ):

From [C++ reference on fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/)

> ```
> istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
> ```
>
> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it.

after this you would pull the first piece of the line, convert to `int` or other number format, use another `getline` to grab the rest of the line ( it automatically delimits at the newline character ), then repeat.